# AWS IAM Policy allows all but specific IAM actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create a policy that allows users to have all IAM actions except any action contains the word "User" or "Group" in the string, so they can still do other actions like: "CreateRole", "ChangePassword", etc.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "iam": [
                        "*User*",
                        "*Group*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But I got this notification: "This policy does not grant any permissions.". I've tried with "StringLike".

According to [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html):

> StringNotLike
>
> Negated case-sensitive matching. The values can include a
>   multi-character match wildcard (*) or a single-character match
>   wildcard (?) anywhere in the string.

If I do this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "iam:*User*",
                "iam:*Group*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "iam:": ["Create*", "Delete*"]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The the policy allows full access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do explicit deny like this. It works but I'm open to better solution.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateGroup",
                "iam:DeleteGroup",
                "iam:UpdateUser",
                "iam:PutUserPermissionsBoundary",
                "iam:AttachUserPolicy",
                "iam:DeleteUserPolicy",
                "iam:UpdateGroup",
                "iam:DeleteUser",
                "iam:DeleteUserPermissionsBoundary",
                "iam:CreateUser",
                "iam:RemoveUserFromGroup",
                "iam:AddUserToGroup",
                "iam:AttachGroupPolicy",
                "iam:PutUserPolicy",
                "iam:DetachGroupPolicy",
                "iam:DetachUserPolicy",
                "iam:DeleteGroupPolicy",
                "iam:PutGroupPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think this is OK. Because you want to "allow everything apart of something". That "something" should be as detailed as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a deny * action to your policy. It would deny everything that was not explicitly allowed.

Take a look at the bellow for an example.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:AddRoleToInstanceProfile",
                "iam:CreateInstanceProfile",
                "iam:DeleteInstanceProfile",
                "iam:GetPolicy",
                "iam:GetPolicyVersion",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
                "iam:ListInstanceProfilesForRole",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:ListPolicies",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
                "iam:RemoveRoleFromInstanceProfile"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },

            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Deny"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I actually had to do this. I thought I could do it with condition. Thank you. Btw, explicit deny would deny all access so you can't really do "Deny" "*".

Comment: denying * denys all but allowed actions